# Android: Programmatically changing XML layout to "Lefty Flip"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to allow users of my app to toggle the UI to be either standard orientation or "lefty flip". I'm unsure how low-level of a solution I need to program, considering Android might provide an abstracted way to easily do this.

Visually, the standard orientation would be: [image: standard layout]

and the lefty flip orientation would be:[image]

So, currently what I'm thinking of attempting is a manual rearrangment of the xml layout, component by component, within a menu button's onTouch() logic.

I get the feeling that there may be a simpler way than this. Any suggestions? Is a series of programmatic calls to rearrange the view the best way? Xml file below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <LinearLayout    
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.40"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/toolbarGestureOverlay" >
    </LinearLayout>  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="3.60"
        android:id="@+id/openglsurface">
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How far back do you want to support?  On 4.2+, you can set the layoutDirection of the top level layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it by using `rotate` function (from API 11 only):

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.yourParentLayout);
view.setRotation(270);
// you must canculate your screen size to make your view fit your screen.
view.getLayoutParams().width = 800;
view.getLayoutParams().height = 480;
// For flip, you can rotate a long x or y axis:
view.setRotationY(180);
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work because the lefty flip view is not a simple rotation of the standard view. The blue view for the lefty flip is not a simple rotation, it is mirrored vertically.

Comment: @Cody Have you ever tried it? Dont you see that it's rotate 180 degree?

Comment: my picture is not detailed enough. The blue layout in the lefty flip image isn't actually rotated, its just inverted along a vertical axis. If I were to rotate the blue layout by 180 degrees it would be upside down (you just can't tell in the picture because the character 'X' looks the same regardless of orientation)